# Displaying image from base64string

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm displaying an image from a base 64 string that came from an API. The problem is, the image is not being displayed.

Here's the code:

```
profilePictureImg.Source = GetUserImage(user.MobileNumber);


private BitmapImage GetUserImage(string phoneNumber)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        var baseAddress = "http://192.168.0.103/vchatapi/api/Images/" + phoneNumber;

        var http = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(new System.Uri(baseAddress));
        http.Accept = "application/json";
        http.ContentType = "application/json";
        http.Method = "GET";

        var response = http.GetResponse();

        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        var content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        var y ="";
        var x = y.FromJson(content);

        byte[] binaryData = Convert.FromBase64String(x);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length))
        {
            ms.Write(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length);
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = ms;

        }
        return bitmapImage;
    }
```

Any Ideas?? Thanks!

EDIT:

Got the fix. For some reason, it requires to call BeginInit and EndInit.

Answer (score 3):

The image may be decoded as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16243638/1136211):

```
var binaryData = Convert.FromBase64String(x);
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(binaryData))
{
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
}
```

The reason why you have to use `BeginInit` and `EndInit` is explained in the Remarks section of the [BitmapImage MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx):

> BitmapImage implements the ISupportInitialize interface to optimize
>   initialization on multiple properties. Property changes can only occur
>   during object initialization. Call BeginInit to signal that
>   initialization has begun and EndInit to signal that initialization has
>   completed. After initialization, property changes are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This may be one of those cases where it pays *not* to dispose the stream too eagerly; also, the `Write` here is unnecessary: you already added the data via the constructor. So just:

```
bitmapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(binaryData);
return bitmapImage;
```

does that work?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But the image is still not displaying.

Comment: then the first thing to check is: was your `binaryData` the bytes you were expecting? i.e. have you successfully obtained the data?

Comment: I will check this. I'm really confident with the binaryData though. Will respond to you after a while.

Comment: Fixed it. For some reason it requires to call bitmapImage.BeginInit and bitmapImage.EndInit. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
byte[] binaryData = Convert.FromBase64String(x);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(binaryData))
{
    bitmapImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```