# XamlWriter image serialization isssue (InvalidOperationException: Property 'UriSource' or property 'StreamSource' must be set.)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, bitmapimage

i am using a ink canvas and added a image to it and then serialize using XamlWriter.

```
Image img = new Image(); 
BitmapImage img = NImageHelper.GetBitmapImageFromString(ImageData, new Size(src.Width, src.Height)); 
img.Source = img;
```

`string Xml = XamlWriter.Save(myCanvas);`

this code works fine, Here is the xml generated

```
<Image Height="100" Width ="150"> 
  <Image.Source> 
     <BitmapImage CacheOption="None" CreateOptions="IgnoreImageCache" BaseUri="{x:Null}"/>
  </Image.Source>
 </Image>
```

In this xml bitmapimage's StreamSource property is not serialized

When i try to parse it back it is throwing exception

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Initialization of 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' threw an exception.' InvalidOperationException: Property 'UriSource' or property 'StreamSource' must be set.

**It works fine if the bitmapimage's UriSource property is set and i am able to parse it back.
but i don't want to set UriSource property.**

Please help me , how to serialize StreamSource property?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what your expectation is about how the Stream should look like in the generated XAML. Is it created from a base64 string?

Comment: `BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
            img.BeginInit();

            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);

            img.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(data);

            img.DecodePixelHeight = decodeVal;

            img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

            RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(img, BitmapScalingMode.LowQuality);
            img.EndInit();
            img.Freeze();`  This is how i generated

Comment: In the above generated xml , there is no image data to render.

Comment: You know you could edit your question? Maybe you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16243638/1136211. Please, also note the correct term is XAML, not XML. And sure, the generated XAML does not contain the source Stream, understood. It's still unclear what you think how it *should* look.

Comment: Thank you so much above link really helped for me..